# C++ program with map - Explain the below program how it's working

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

In the below program, tmp_data is printing first as : "Ravindra Kumar". But after copying into the map it's changed to "RRRRRRRRRRR". When we print next time, it's still printing "Ravindra Kumar" - how. It suppose to print RRRRRRRR right ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void fun_call( );
main(){
        cout << "printing all data " << endl ;

        fun_call();
        fun_call();

}

void fun_call()
{
      //  static void *tmp_data;
        void *tmp_data;
        char *str="Ravindra Kumar";
        char *str1="RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR";
        char name[]="Ravi";
        char value[100];

        static std::map<std::string,void *> name_data_map;
        std::map<std::string,void *>::iterator iter   ;

        iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;

        if ( iter == name_data_map.end())
        {
        tmp_data = (void *) malloc ( strlen(str)+1 );
        memcpy(tmp_data,str,strlen(str)+1);
        name_data_map[name]=tmp_data;
        cout << "Inside the if" << endl ;
        }
        cout << "Outside the if" << endl ;
        iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;

        memcpy(value,iter->second,strlen(str)+1);
        cout << "value is " << value <<  endl ;
        tmp_data=(void *)malloc(100000);
        memcpy(tmp_data,str1,strlen(str1)+1);

}
```

output :

```
$ ./a.out
printing all data
Inside the if
Outside the if
value is Ravindra Kumar
Outside the if
value is Ravindra Kumar
```

Comment: The broken signature of your main function suggests you are using a noncompliant compiler. which is it?

Comment: Added the `c` tag as this is in fact more of a C issue than C++.

Comment: How is this a C issue? `using`, `namespace`, `cout`, `map`, `string`, `::`, abuse of `<` and `>` are all so not C!

Comment: @pmg, check the actual problem of the OP. It has to do with a `void*` pointer, which the OP `malloc`ed twice and `memcpy`d the contents of two `char*` text strings into it. You could replace `std::map` with an array, `cout` with `printf` and drop all the rest of the C++ stuff without affecting the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

You copy `"RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"` into `tmp_data`, then exit the function, discarding `tmp_data` altogether (btw without freeing it, so you have a memory leak there). The next call to `fun_call` will create a new `tmp_data` local variable, whose value has no relation to what you set it before to. However, `name_data_map` is declared `static`, so it is allocated only once (on the first call to `fun_call`), and reused afterwards, keeping the value you put into it in the previous call (and that value is in fact a different memory block from the one you copy the R's into later).

#### Update - a more detailed explanation

Here

```
    tmp_data = (void *) malloc ( strlen(str)+1 );
    memcpy(tmp_data,str,strlen(str)+1);
    name_data_map[name]=tmp_data;
```

you allocate a memory block, copy "Ravindra Kumar" into it and store a pointer to it in the map. At this point, `name_data_map[name]` and `tmp_data` point to the same memory block. Graphically it might roughly look something like this (assuming, for the sake of simplicity, that the two text literals are stored in memory consecutively, which may or may not be the case in real life):

```
name_data_map[name] ----
                        ˇ
tmp_data ---------------
                        ˇ
raw memory    ..........Ravindra Kumar\0RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\0............
```

If you modified the contents of that memory block (by e.g. copying a different text into `tmp_data`) the change would be visible through `name_data_map[name]` too, since both of these point to the same memory location.

However, this would not work vice versa: after changing the map value, e.g.

```
    name_data_map[name]=str1;
```

the program state would look like this:

```
name_data_map[name] --------------------
                                        ˇ
tmp_data ---------------
                        ˇ
raw memory    ..........Ravindra Kumar\0RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR\0............
```

making the two pointers point to different locations, thus a change in one would not affect the other. So note that there is a fundamental difference between changing the value of a *pointer*, vs changing the value of the *memory* it points to.

You do exactly the former a few lines later, just with `tmp_data`:

```
    tmp_data=(void *)malloc(100000);
    memcpy(tmp_data,str1,strlen(str1)+1);
```

The first line changes the value of `tmp_data`, so now it no more points to the same place as `name_data_map[name]`! After that, whatever you do with the newly allocated memory block, it won't affect `name_data_map[name]` anymore. This is why you failed to change it.

> If we declare the map as non static, than we can change it right ?

Wrong. Declaring your map `static` has no effect on this - it only affects the scope of your map. A nonstatic map would cease to exist when you exit from `fun_call`, losing all the values stored in it. While it is alive, you can change its values, regardless of it being `static` or not. You just need to use the right pointer for it.

If your aim was to change the value stored in the map via `tmp_data`, just drop the second `malloc` and modify the first one to allocate a longer block (as `str1` is longer than `str`, so trying to copy `str1` into a buffer having the length of `str` results in buffer overrun, i.e. undefined behaviour). After that, you should have a working - although nasty - code, as it is generally not a good idea to try and modify values in a map "behind its back". Moreover, mixing C constructs (`malloc` and raw pointers, especially `void*`) in C++ code is a Bad Idea. If you are only experimenting, it is acceptable - bot please don't ever do this in production code. And your intention was something different, please clarify.

Comment: That's what i am doing there. I am copying and coming back to the main and than calling again. But still tmp_data pointing to the old data.

Comment: @user1044923, no, `tmp_data` has nothing to do with this. You allocate two distinct memory blocks, copy "Ravindra Kumar" into the first and store it in the map. Then copy a sequence of R's into the second, and abandon it. That second memory block is lost forever, as after exiting the function, you have no pointer pointing to it.

Comment: okay. Once we store it into the map, we can't change the value inside the map by modifying the tmp_data. If we declare the map as non static, than we can change it right ?

Comment: The address in tmp_data is changed by malloc, so after the first malloc, you put the address in the map, but after the next malloc, that address in tmp_data has been changed and has nothing to do with the address in the map.  This has nothing to do with tmp_data being static or not.

Comment: If you end the function with "name_data_map[name]=tmp_data;", then you have your result, but you still have a memory leak, which you don't have with the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is simpler and seems to do what you want.  Is there any reason to prefer char* over std::string as value in the map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void fun_call()
{
        const char* str="Ravindra Kumar";
        const char* str1="RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR";
        const char* name="Ravi";

        static std::map<std::string,std::string> name_data_map;
        std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator iter;

        iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;

        if ( iter == name_data_map.end())
        {
          name_data_map[name]=str;
          cout << "Inside the if" << endl ;
        }
        cout << "Outside the if" << endl ;
        iter=name_data_map.find(name) ;
        cout << "value is " << iter->second <<  endl ;
        iter->second = str1;
}

main(){
        cout << "printing all data " << endl ;

        fun_call();
        fun_call();
}
```

Output:

```
printing all data 
Inside the if
Outside the if
value is Ravindra Kumar
Outside the if
value is RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```